# CSS Tooltip Positioning / Chrome vs IE 11

Tags: css, internet-explorer-11

I've added a custom weather web part to my SharePoint page, but I want a hover message that displays additional info.

The pieces I've got worked out look great in Chrome, but not so great in IE 11. I need this to look the same in both - any tips?

```
    .tooltip {
        display:inline;
        position: relative;
        font-family:Arial,Helvetica,sans-serif;
        font-size:9pt;
    }
    .tooltip:hover:after {
        background: #333;
        background: rgba(0,0,0,.8);
        border-radius: 5px;
        top: 6px;
        color: #fff;
        content: attr(title);
        left: 5px;
        padding: 5px 15px;
        position: absolute;
        z-index: 98;
        width: 220px;
        /*width: auto;*/
    }
    .tooltip:hover:before {
        border: solid;
        border-color: #333 transparent;
        border-width: 0 6px 6px 6px;
        top: 40px;
        content: "";
        left: 25px;
        position: absolute;
        z-index: 99;
    }
```

Here's my JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/hcoa82wb/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was the `.tooltip` tag using the `display: inline` When this is changed to `display: inline-block` both IE and Chrome began to show the messed up version of the tool-tip. From there it was just a matter of changing the `top` properties to display how you would want it. [Here is your JS Fiddle updated](http://jsfiddle.net/hcoa82wb/2/). I left comments in the CSS code.

On the same note I would recommend using a different Class name other than `.tooltip` I would hate for you to run into issues in the future if someone adds a WebPart or a 3rd party SharePoint plug-in that uses the same class name. I've had issues with that in the past.

Comment: Awesome. Thank you so much! I will rename the .tooltip based on your recommendation.